# How to use Custom Action for Condition?

Tags: service, wix, conditional-statements

I need to check if some service already installed in system before continue installation.
I.e. I have added

```xml
<Condition Message="Svc must be installed">
    Installed OR SVC_V1
</Condition>
```

But I can check if it is installed only by using Custom Action because Svc is Windows Service. How I can use CA for this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need custom action for detecting your service. Services get registered under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\` so you can use **RegistrySearch**:

```
<Property Id="SVC_V1">
  <RegistrySearch Id='RegSampleService'
                  Type='raw'
                  Root='HKLM' 
                  Name='ImagePath'
                  Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\YourService" />
</Property>
```

Note however that Registry read permissions are required.

Comment: I've typically used a custom action because we wanted to know if the service was set to automatic and running not only that it existed.

Comment: True but he requested to "check if some service already installed".

Comment: Yes, understood.  But being a defensive programmer, usually when someone asks this question it means they have a dependency on the service actually running.   For example, checking that mssqlserver is present and/or running would have a big effect on an installer.

Answer (score 2):

Custom Actions set properties that then can be used to evaluate a condition.